# How to combine Flow<List<T>> with Flow<Map<T, List<V>>>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

I am trying to convert multiple Flow results from different @Query on Room database to a single list

```
data class Location
data class WeatherLogs
data class LocationWeatherLogs(val location: Location, val weatherLogs: List<WeatherLogs>)

getLocations(): Flow<List<Location>>
getWeatherLogs(): Flow<Map<Location, List<WeatherLogs>>>
```

result that I'm expecting is `Flow<List<LocationWeatherLogs>>`

getWeatherLogs might not have all the locations. The map only has locations that have WeatherLogs. For location that doesn't have weather logs, the weatherLogs list will be emptyList

I'm not sure how to go through each location in the location list

Comment: Can you add the @Query? It think most of what you are doing can be done with a single annotation.

Comment: Could you please clarify the steps of your use case? Do you need to call `getLocations()` while `getWeatherLogs()` result already contains `WeatherLogs` information bound to a location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can solve this with Room directly.
Solving this in Kotlin his would look like:

```
val locationWeatherLogs: Flow<List<LocationWeatherLogs>> =
    combine(getLocations(), getWeatherLogs()) { location, weatherLogs ->
        location.map {
            LocationWeatherLogs(
                location = it,
                weatherLogs = weatherLogs[it] ?: emptyList()
            )
        }
    }
```

On a Sidenote: you might want to replace your getters with `vals`?

Comment: That works. Thank you.
I tried to solve it from Room directly but can't find a query that get the location even when there's no weather logs on that location.

getLocations() and getWeatherLogs() are just for simplicity's sake. They are actually the repository functions.